# Replacing different files from different folders

Tags: files, find, replace

He everybody,

I couldn't find an answer to my question, so here goes:

I want to make a "job" that replaces / distributes 10000+ PDF-files from 1 directory to a unique folder where "the same" PDF (only PDF name is the same) is already.

Example: directories with 10000+ PDF-files = /my_dir/backup
there are 10000+ random PDF's, like `143079.pdf`, `493857.pdf` and `888675.pdf`

The "job" has to search for the folder where `143079.pdf` is already in, for example: its located in `/os_dir/pdf/EDFR_29384_euendho` and replace it. So the "job" will see `/my_dir/backup/143079.pdf` and start searching in the folder on `/os_dir/pdf/` and will find it in `/os_dir/pdf/EDFR_29384_euendho/`. He has to replace `143079.pdf` in `/os_dir/pdf/EDFR_29384_euendho/` with the `143079.pdf` from `/my_dir/backup/`. He has to do this 10000+ times with all random PDF's and all random folders.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec bash -c \
'p="/my_dir/backup/"; bn=${1##*/}; 
 [[ "$1" != $p* ]] && [[ -f "${p}$bn" ]] && cp "${p}$bn" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

---

- `p="/my_dir/backup/"` - path to the initial (crucial) directory
- `bn=${1##*/}` - file's basename